SAS Enterprise Guide Creating Date Range Prompt
I created a date range prompt using SAS Enterprise Guide Prompt Manager. I right click the prompt to see its related macro variables.
1- I just want to run the program and select the prompt values. When I run the project, prompt screen appears. I had an excel prompt already which appears, but my second date range prompt doesn't seem.
2- I want to use the date range related macros in my code. When I right click the prompt to see its macros, a lot of options appear. I selected the first one to see what happens. (which was date_pmt_min). I chose the date type as month by the way (example: July 2024)
%let str_date = "&date_pmt_min"d;
%put start date: &str_date ;

The code above doesnt print a value to the log.
How can I see the result in log & see the prompt in prompt screen?
Thanks in advance.

In principle, with the above code, you should see the value of the macro variable value in the log. What are you actually seeing in the log? E.g. do you see the string "start date:"?
Also, what do you mean by "see the prompt in prompt screen"?

I mean when I run the .egp file, the "Specify Values for Project Prompts" editor opens. I see my select file prompt but I do not see any date range related prompt that I can select my range and run the program according to that.

after you created the prompt you need to assign it to a program.
Follow the steps below to do so.
Open the properties on the program

Assign the prompt via the Add Button

If you run the program the prompt automatically create the following variables

To show the values you can just use the %put function without the need to assign a new local variable.
Here yu see the code and the result in the log file


Oh got it, thanks a lot!
